# Esempi di uso di "accodarsi" in senso figurato

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Il verbo ["accodarsi"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/accodare/) significa in modo letterale "mettersi in fila". Tuttavia, in un'intervista alla giornalista Eleonora Bianchini con motivo della pubblicazione del suo saggio *Il libro che la Lega Nord non ti farebbe mai leggere* che ho ascoltato a lezione, mi sono accorta di un uso figurato di tale verbo che mi è sembrato interessante. Non sono purtroppo in grado di riprodurre la frase esatta in cui l'ho sentito, ma la struttura dell'espressione era

> persone che si accodano a qualcosa.

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/accodare/) ho trovato questi esempi di uso di tale verbo con questo senso figurato:

> *accodarsi al conformismo delle idee, alla maggioranza*

Mi piacerebbe però avere altri esempi di utilizzazione di "accodarsi" con questo significato figurato in modo che possa capire meglio come usarlo. Me li potreste fare?

Comment: Il senso figurato di solito indica “seguire acriticamente”, con un senso alquanto peggiorativo, come negli esempi; *aggregarsi* ha, a mio parere un senso meno negativo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Penso che il significato a cui ti riferisci sia quello definito dal [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/accodarsi) come:

> - 2. fig., ***seguire acriticamente le teorie, l’esempio di qcn***.: accodarsi al conformismo dilagante

Da  [La fine dell'era Americana](https://books.google.it/books?id=TsHTcg_SHEAC&pg=PR21&dq=%22accodarsi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqkuT7uavSAhVBsiwKHWg_CV0Q6AEIRzAK#v=onepage&q=%22accodarsi%22&f=false), Charles A. Kupchan - 2003:

> - Di conseguenza, è più probabile che gli altri Stati provino risentimento piuttosto che rispetto per la potenza americana, ***e che quindi si oppongano anziché accodarsi alla leadership statunitense.***

Da [Roberto Farinacci, ovvero, Della rivoluzione fascista](https://books.google.it/books?id=QoloAAAAMAAJ&q=%22accodarsi%22&dq=%22accodarsi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqkuT7uavSAhVBsiwKHWg_CV0Q6AEIODAH), Giuseppe Pardini - 2007:

> - liberali rivendicarono «assoluta autonomia» e ***sostennero che non volevano «accodarsi al fascismo», ma «fiancheggiarlo»,*** collaborare lealmente come avveniva nel governo nazionale (G. Occhioni, Lettera aperta all'on Farinacci, ...

Answer (score 2):

Quest'accezione del verbo accodarsi può essere utilizzata per frasi del tipo: *"[mi accodo alla domanda](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22mi+accodo+alla+domanda%22) fatta da X"* o *"[mi accodo alla richiesta](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22mi+accodo+alla+richiesta%22) dell'utente X"*.

Il senso è: *"sono interessato alla stessa richiesta/domanda fatta già da qualcun altro"* quindi *mi accodo* in attesa che qualcuno risponda alla domanda o soddisfi la richiesta.